# Flutter Provider rebuilt widget before parent's Consumer

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have got a problem with the provider package.

I want to be able to clean an attribute (`_user = null`) of a provider `ChangeNotifier` class (it is a logout feature).

The problem is when I am doing that from a Widget that use info from this Provider.

My main app is like :

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AuthProvider(),
      builder: (context, _) => App(),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AuthProvider>(builder: (_, auth, __) {
      Widget displayedWidget;
      switch (auth.loginState) {
        case ApplicationLoginState.initializing:
          displayedWidget = LoadingAppScreen();
          break;
        case ApplicationLoginState.loggedIn:
          displayedWidget = HomeScreen();
          break;
        case ApplicationLoginState.loggedOut:
        default:
          displayedWidget = AuthenticationScreen(
            signInWithEmailAndPassword: auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword,
            registerAccount: auth.registerAccount,
          );
      }

      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        home: displayedWidget,
        routes: {
          ProfileScreen.routeName: (_) => ProfileScreen(),
        },
      );
    });
  }
}
```

My Provider class (simplified) :

```dart
class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ApplicationLoginState _loginState;
  ApplicationLoginState get loginState => _loginState;

  bool get loggedIn => _loginState == ApplicationLoginState.loggedIn;

  User _user;
  User get user => _user;

  void signOut() async {
    // Cleaning the user which lead to the error later
    _user = null;
    _loginState = ApplicationLoginState.loggedOut;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

My Profile screen which is accessible via named Route

```dart
class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/profile';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final User user = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context).user;

    return Scaffold(
      // drawer: AppDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text(user.displayName),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('logout'),
            onPressed: () {
              // Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
              //   context,
              //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => App()),
              //   ModalRoute.withName('/'),
              // );
              Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).signOut();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I click the logout button from the profile screen, I don't understand why i get the error :

[image: Error displayed]

As I am using a `Consumer<AuthProvider>` at the top level of my app (this one includes my route (ProfileScreen), I thought it would redirect to the `AuthenticationScreen` due to the `displayedWidget` computed from the `switch`.

But it seems to rebuild the `ProfileScreen` first leading to the error. the change of `displayedWidget` do not seems to have any effect.

I'm pretty new to Provider. I don't understand what I am missing in the Provider pattern here ? Is my `App` / `Consumer` wrongly used ?

I hope you can help me understand what I've done wrong here ! Thank you.

*Note :* the commented `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil` redirect correctly to the login screen but I can see the error screen within a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your user is null, and you tried to get the name of him. You need to check it before using it. It will look like this:

```
   user == null ?
     Text("User Not Found!"),
     Text(user.displayName),
```

Comment: I know `user` is null. My question is more on why the `ProfileScreen` widget is rebuild before the top level `App` (which use a `Consumer`). As `ProfileScreen` is a private route it should be displayed only If I have a user. So I dont want to check in that widget if my user is null or not.

Answer (score 0):

From the provider API reference of [`Provider.of`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Provider/of.html) :

> Obtains the nearest Provider up its widget tree and returns its
> value.
>
> If listen is true, later value changes will trigger a new State.build
> to widgets, and State.didChangeDependencies for StatefulWidget.

So I think the line `final User user = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context).user;` in your profile screen calls a rebuild when the _user variable is modified, and then the _user can be null in your ProfileScreen.

Have you tried to `Navigator.pop` the profile screen before clearing the _user variable?